# isinstance and type between modules

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to check the type of base_geo in this setter.

```
    @base_geo.setter
    def base_geo(self, base_geo):
        test_geo = Geo(self.data_node, "foo_geo")

        print "inspect module base_geo: %s" % inspect.getmodule(base_geo)
        print "inspect module Geo: %s" % inspect.getmodule(Geo)

        print "type base_geo: %s" % type(base_geo)
        print "base_geo: %s" % base_geo
        print "base_geo.__class__: %s" % base_geo.__class__
        print "Geo: %s" % Geo
        print "type(base_geo) == Geo: %s" % str(type(base_geo) == Geo)
        print "isinstance(base_geo, Geo): %s" % isinstance(base_geo, Geo)
        print "base_geo.__class__ == Geo: %s\n" % str(base_geo.__class__ == Geo)

        print "___TEST__GEO___"
        print "inspect module test_geo: %s" % inspect.getmodule(test_geo)
        print "inspect module Geo: %s" % inspect.getmodule(Geo)

        print "type test_geo: %s" % type(test_geo)
        print "test_geo: %s" % test_geo
        print "test_geo.__class__: %s" % test_geo.__class__
        print "Geo: %s" % Geo
        print "type(test_geo) == Geo: %s" % str(type(test_geo) == Geo)
        print "isinstance(test_geo, Geo): %s" % isinstance(test_geo, Geo)
        print "test_geo.__class__ == Geo: %s" % str(test_geo.__class__ == Geo)

        if not isinstance(base_geo, Geo):
            raise TypeError, ("%s is not of type \"Geo\"" % base_geo)
        self._base_geo = base_geo
```

Which outputs the following

```
inspect module base_geo: <module 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo' from 'Q:\tools\Maya\grinder\scripts\deformator\builderator\data_types\geo.py'>
inspect module Geo: <module 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo' from 'Q:\tools\Maya\grinder\scripts\deformator\builderator\data_types\geo.py'>
type base_geo: <class 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo'>
base_geo: <deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo object at 0x0000016DFD0E77B8>
base_geo.__class__: <class 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo'>
Geo: <class 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo'>
type(base_geo) == Geo: False
isinstance(base_geo, Geo): False
base_geo.__class__ == Geo: False

___TEST__GEO___
inspect module test_geo: <module 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo' from 'Q:\tools\Maya\grinder\scripts\deformator\builderator\data_types\geo.py'>
inspect module Geo: <module 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo' from 'Q:\tools\Maya\grinder\scripts\deformator\builderator\data_types\geo.py'>
type test_geo: <class 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo'>
test_geo: <deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo object at 0x0000016DFD3E7A90>
test_geo.__class__: <class 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo'>
Geo: <class 'deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo'>
type(test_geo) == Geo: True
isinstance(test_geo, Geo): True
test_geo.__class__ == Geo: True
# Error: TypeError: file Q:\tools\Maya\grinder\scripts\deformator\builderator\data_types\channels.py line 236: <deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo object at 0x0000016DFD0E77B8> is not of type "Geo" #
```

Any ideas as to why the test_geo case is working as expected while base_geo is not? The only difference i can think of is that base_geo is constructed in a different module. Other examples of people having similar issues seems to have been resolved by keeping the imports the same between modules, which they already are in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isinstance(base_geo, deformator.builderator.data_types.geo.Geo)
```

instead of

```
isinstance(base_geo, Geo)
```

solved it